# Active window screen capture and reduce size while capturing

Tags: c#, size, screen, scale, capture

I am trying to screen capture the active window with that code below. But this code is capturing the exact screen size and draining 200MB of memory. Actually, I only need 320x180 pixels resolution and less memory usage. Is there any way to reduce size while screen capturing?

```
        public Bitmap Capture(enmScreenCaptureMode screenCaptureMode = enmScreenCaptureMode.Window)
    {
        Rectangle bounds;

        if (screenCaptureMode == enmScreenCaptureMode.Screen)
        {
            bounds = Screen.GetBounds(System.Drawing.Point.Empty);
            CursorPosition = Cursor.Position;
        }
        else
        {
            var foregroundWindowsHandle = GetForegroundWindow();
            var rect = new Rect();
            GetWindowRect(foregroundWindowsHandle, ref rect);
            bounds = new Rectangle(rect.Left, rect.Top, rect.Right - rect.Left, rect.Bottom - rect.Top);
            CursorPosition = new System.Drawing.Point(Cursor.Position.X - rect.Left, Cursor.Position.Y - rect.Top);
        }
            var result = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height);

            using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(result))
            {
                g.CopyFromScreen(new System.Drawing.Point(bounds.Left, bounds.Top), System.Drawing.Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
            }


        return result;
    }
```

Comment: If you need high-performance screen capture without taking up memory, you could use the LEADTOOLS Multimedia SDK and its [Screen Capture Filter](https://leadtools.com/help/sdk/v22/multimedia/filters/lead-screen-capture-filter-user-interface-2-0.html). This filter, along with LEADTOOLS [Capture control](https://leadtools.com/help/sdk/v22/dh/multimedia/mm/capturectrl.html) allow you to capture the active window directly to a video file with the option to use video codecs to perform compression. If you would like to try the SDK, there’s a free evaluation [here](https://leadtools.com/downloads).

Comment: Disclosure: I work for the LEADTOOLS vendors.